# Combining list items together to form a third list (i.e. list1; 1, 2, 3. list2; a, b, c. list3; 1a, 2b, 3c.)

Tags: c#

there.

I have two XmlNode lists. I want to combine these either into a third list or ideally straight into a checkbox list where each item that corresponds with the other list's item through their indexes produces an output that combines the items, i.e. list1; 1, 2, 3. list2; a, b, c. list3; 1a, 2b, 3c.

*NOT*  "1, 2, 3, a, b, c."

The code I have uses two foreach loops but outputs every possible combination, and I know why, I just can't seem to find the right code so this is just an example of where I'm at.

```
            var lsMac = xnList.Cast<XmlNode>().Select(node => node.InnerText);
            var lsDisp = xnList1.Cast<XmlNode>().Select(node => node.InnerText);
            foreach (var m in lsMac)
            {
                foreach (var d in lsDisp)
                {
                    chkboxMAC.Items.Add(m + " " + d);
                }
            }
```

Maybe Join would be a good method to use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Zip from Linq.

```
var lsMac = xnList.Cast<XmlNode>().Select(node => node.InnerText);
var lsDisp = xnList1.Cast<XmlNode>().Select(node => node.InnerText);
var result = lsMac.Zip(lsDisp, (m, d) => m + " " + d);
foreach(var x in result) chkboxMAC.Items.Add(x);
```

Zip will enumerate two enumerables together.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `LINQ.ZIP` for this purpose

here is fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/5uCqZm

Something along the lines of

```
  var foo= new List<int> {1, 2, 3};
    var bar= new List<string> {"a", "b", "c"};

     var result = foo.Zip(bar, (a, b) => {
        return a.ToString() + b;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `Zip()` in other answers you can use `Select()`:

```
var result = lsMac.Select((item, index) => item + " " + lsDisp.ElementAt(index));
```

Or call `ToList()` to get element by index using `[]`:

```
var lsDispList = lsDisp.ToList();
var result = lsMac.Select((item, index) => item + " " + lsDispList[index]);
```

Comment: And it's complexity is pretty high On(n^2) vs O(n) for the zip solution.